# How to accommodate the text on a button according to the size of that button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to add a tiny button on my frame on which it's written `x`. But due to the small size of the button, it's not getting desired output.

Is there a way I can create a small button as well can add a visible `x` on it?

Below is my current code:

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;
// import javax.swing.Font;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;  

class Sm
{
    JFrame f;JButton b;
    Sm()
    {
        f=new JFrame("asd");
        b=new JButton("x");

        b.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD,5));

        f.setSize(100,100);
        b.setBounds(40,40,20,20);
        f.add(b);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new Sm();
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a null-layout, please take a look at [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). With some of them you could then use `setMargin(Insets)` to reduce the inner spacing.

Comment: Can you give name of a specific layout manager using which i can do this ?

Comment: You could try with a default `FlowLayout` or `GridBagLayout`, if you want the button to be centered both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @LuxxMiner  , import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;
// import javax.swing.Font;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;  

class Sm
{
 JFrame f;
 // JButton b;
 Sm()
 {
  f=new JFrame("asd");
  //       b=new JButton("x");
  // b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
  // b.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD,5));
   AbstractButton jb = new JButton("x");
   jb.setBounds(40,40,20,20);
         jb.setMargin(new Insets(0,5,15,15));


  f.setSize(100,100);
  

  
  f.add(jb);
  f.setLayout(null);
  f.setVisible(true);
 }

 public static void main(String s[])
 {
  new Sm();
 }
}

Comment: So what were you trying to achieve here? If you want minimal margins, call `setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0)` - But it wouldn't have any effect on the button size in your code, because you're still using a null-layout and `setBounds()`.

Comment: @LuxxMiner, Thanks,it's working

Comment: Short answer is don't, you've got your problem backwards, you should let the button and layout managers make these decisions based on the text and font properties